# Capturar el valor de DropdownButtonFormField en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito capturar el valor seleccionado para poder enviarlo como parámetro. Estoy trabajando con Flutter (Dart) y [supabase](/questions/tagged/supabase) como base de datos.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/models/area_model.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/models/cargo_model.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/models/cce_model.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/models/boss_model.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/models/modality_model.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/services/db_service.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}


class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bussines_nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final dbService = Provider.of<DbService>(context);
    // Using below conditions because build can be called multiple times
    dbService.allCce.isEmpty ? dbService.getAllCce() : null;
    dbService.allArea.isEmpty ? dbService.getAllArea() : null;
    dbService.allCargo.isEmpty ? dbService.getAllCargo() : null;
    dbService.allBoss.isEmpty ? dbService.getAllBoss() : null;
    dbService.allModality.isEmpty ? dbService.getAllModality() : null;

  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Form(
                //key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text("Employee Email ID"),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            controller: _emailController,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text("Password"),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text("name"),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            controller: _nameController,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text("Razón social"),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            controller: _bussines_nameController,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
```

//Aquí muestro la información en una lista directamente desde supabase:

```dart
 dbService.allCce.isEmpty
      ? const LinearProgressIndicator()
      : SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
            hint: Text('Select CCE'),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            // value: dbService.userCce ?? dbService.allCce.first.id,
            items:
                dbService.allCce.map((CceModel item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: item.id,
                  child: Text(
                    item.ccostos,
                    style:
                        const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ));
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (_selectedval) {
              dbService.userCce = _selectedval;
              print(_selectedval);
            },
          ),
        ),
```

//Aquí nos dirige a otra clase llamada registerWorker enviándole los siguientes parámetros:
`_emailController.text.trim(),_passwordController.text.trim(), _nameController.text.trim()`

//Aquí necesitaría enviar el parámetro de DropdownButtonFormField

```dart
   Consumer<AuthService>(
    builder: (context, authServiceProvider, child) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: authServiceProvider.isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  authServiceProvider.registerWorker(
                      _emailController.text.trim(),
                      _passwordController.text.trim(),
                      _nombreController.text.trim(),
                      _razonController.text.trim(),
                      //_selectedCCE.toInt(),

                      context);
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                child: const Text(
                  "REGISTER",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

//clase auth_service - registerWorker

```dart
    Future registerWorker(
      String email, String password, String name, String business_name ,BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      setIsLoading = true;
      if (email == "" || password == "") {
        throw ("All Fields are required");
      }
      final AuthResponse response =
      await _supabase.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password);
      if (response != null) {
        await _dbService.insertNewUser(email, response.user!.id, name
            );

        Utils.showSnackBar("Successfully registered !", context,
            color: Colors.green);
        await loginWorker(email, password, context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setIsLoading = false;
      Utils.showSnackBar(e.toString(), context, color: Colors.blueAccent);
    }
  }
```

//clase db_service - insertNewUser

```dart
 class DbService extends ChangeNotifier {
      final SupabaseClient _supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
    
        List<CceModel> allCce = [];
        int? userCce;
    
      String generateRandomUserId() {
        final random = Random();
        const allChars = "faangFAANG0123456789";
        final randomString =
        List.generate(8, (index) => allChars[random.nextInt(allChars.length)])
            .join();
        return randomString;
      }
    
    
  Future<void> getAllCce() async {
    final List result =
    await _supabase.from(Constants.cceTable).select();
    allCce = result
        .map((cce) => CceModel.fromJson(cce))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
    
    
    Future insertNewUser(String email,var id,String name, String business_name ) async {
        await _supabase.from(Constants.userTable).insert({
          'id': id,
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'user_id': generateRandomUserId(),
    
        });
      }
```

Comment: Que valor quieres extraer del dropdown con exactitud? Y en la otra clase que parámetro quieres mostrar.

Comment: Hola Jonathan, el valor seleccionado de _selectedval , cuando presiono en el boton registrar nos lleva a la clase authServiceProvider en el metodo registerWorker previamente enviandole _emailController.text.trim(), _passwordController.text.trim() y demas, es en esa parte donde no se como enviarle esa variable del valor seleccionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu comentario, lo que deberías hacer es crear una variable global para poder almacenar el valor seleccionado del `dropdownButton`:

```
CceModel? modelSelected;
```

Una vez hayas declarado la variable que en un principio podría ser nula, en la propiedad `onChanged` del `dropdownButton` tienes que asignarle el valor a la variable:

```
  onChanged: (_selectedval) {
      //dbService.userCce = _selectedval;
      setState(() => modelSelected = _selectedval);
      print(_selectedval);
  }
```

Y en el botón donde navegas a la siguiente pantalla simplemente le pasas los parámetros que ya tienes asigandos en la variable `modalSelected`, ej:

```
Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => NextPage(id: modelSelected.id, name: modelSelected.name)));
```

o basandonos en tu código sería:

```
    onPressed: () {
        authServiceProvider.registerWorker(
          modelSelected.email,//_emailController.text.trim(),
          modelSelected.password,//_passwordController.text.trim(),
          modelSelected.nombre,//_nombreController.text.trim(),
          modelSelected.razon,//_razonController.text.trim(),
        //_selectedCCE.toInt(), context);
   },
```

Comment: Agregue la variable global y le asigne el valor a la variable ya con eso pude capturar el valor, gracias Jonatan Perez.

Answer (score 0):

Agregué la variable global y le asigné el valor a la variable. Ya con eso pude capturar el valor.

```dart
      var modelSelected_cce;

      onChanged: (_selectedval) {
      //dbService.userCce = _selectedval;
      setState(() => modelSelected = _selectedval);
      print(_selectedval);
  }
```

Comment: No es necesario dar las gracias al usuario que te ayudó, si quieres agradecerle marca su respuesta como correcta o vota positivo, es la forma en la que se agradece en SO. ;)